# How to get ID against selected value of Dropdownlist C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the ID against the selected value of a DropDownList which is bound with DB?

Then how can I insert this ID into another table?

To get ID code

```
string query = "Select ID From Table-1 Where Name=" + DropDwonList.SelectedValue;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string getId = dr[0].ToString();
```

DropDownList Binding Code

```
string query = "Select ID, Name from Table-1";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DropDwonList.DataSource = dt;
DropDwonList.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDwonList.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDwonList.DataBind();
DropDwonList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Did you set the DataValueField and DataTextField properties?

Comment: I edited my main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `string Id = DropDwonList.SelectedValue;`

2) To insert into another table just use a query:

```
string Id = DropDwonList.SelectedValue;

        using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string query = @"INSERT INTO TABLE2(Column1)
                               VALUES(" + Id + ")";
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = sql;
            sql.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sql.Close();
        }
```

You should do it this way because you always ensure that you are closing a connection after using it.